# iOS listenable future pattern similar to java

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, callback

I was just curious to know whether iOS has some feature similar to listenable future pattern in java.Or can we achieve this somehow in iOS?In iOS we have only delegates and blocks as callback?.Thanks.

Comment: delegate protocol pattern, blocks, NSNotificationCenter, KVO, and even simple property crawling, check them all out!

Comment: *only* blocks... I think blocks are a really powerful mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a look on [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa). developed by GitHub.

It works on FRP Design pattern.